# Add a shadow under a header bar in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, header

Do you know how I can add a shadow under a header bar in a UITableView ?

By the way, there is only one header.

Here is an example : [image]

Thanks, Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try experimenting with the following method (from `UITableViewDataSoruce`):

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

This allows you to set a custom view for your table view headers, and you could therefore put a custom image with drop shadow on.

Comment: well I thought about it but the shadow should be on the under cell, i'll edit my post with a photoshop screenshot

Comment: Finally I created a bigger view, including the header and the shadow. Then I created 2 PNGs, one for the header, the other one, a little transparent, for the shadow. I added these two subviews with the function you adviced me, it works nicely.